# Optimisation Problem with a stochastic integral

Tags: optimization, quantitative-finance

I am reading the following paper about forecasting interest rates: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/for.2783.

In section 3.2.3 - the Hull-White model, it mentions that the parameters can be found by solving the optimization problem to minimize the difference between actual and model interest rates:
[optimisation problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6wIS.png)

The model interest rate is given by the solution of the Hull-White equation which involves a stochastic integral as shown here:
[interest rate solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEWiT.png)

Is there a well known method to deal with this kind of problem? Thank you!